# Toggle Circles on Google Map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use a simple function to just hide my circles around my markers in Google Maps API.  The error I am getting is "**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setVisble'**."

Here is the function:

```
// Toggles circles
function toggleCircles() {
    if (circlesArray) {
        for (i in circlesArray) {
            circlesArray[i].setVisble(false);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it live here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BWXwf/58/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo error:

setVisible not setVisble

```
function toggleCircles() {
    if (circlesArray) {
        for (i in circlesArray) {
            circlesArray[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, you could set directly property instead of calling a function:

```
circlesArray[i].visible = false;
```